# Servicing webserver clients as "guests"?

Tags: c, http, webserver, file-permissions

I recently implemented a simple webserver in C. However, I've run into somewhat of a security issue.

Currently, when I get a request for GET, I do the following:

- Parse the header
- If valid header, check if we have file permissions
- If we have permissions, send the file
- If we don't have permissions, send `403 Forbidden`
- If the file doesn't exist, send `404 Not Found`
- Otherwise, send `400 Bad Request`

However, since the webserver does this itself, it uses *its* permissions and privileges when servicing the clients. In other words, this means that the only way (currently) for my webserver to display a `403 Forbidden` is if even the user who starts the webserver has no read privileges on the file.

Obviously, this is a problem.

My question is the following: is it possible to stat `group` or `others` flags for read/write permissions as opposed to just `user`? I use `open()` to check for permissions currently - would I have to use something else?

Comment: What is your goal for this webserver? Are you trying to enable a single webserver that can server documents owned by various users in a Unix multi-user environment?

Comment: You might like to read `man setuid` and its `SEE ALSO`s.

Comment: @MultimediaMike Yes, something like that. It is a very simple project, so I don't have quite that far a vision for it yet, but I thought that it would need to be addressed at one point or another. alk, Thank you for that suggestion. It seems to be closest to what I was searching for, so if you wish to post it as an answer, I will accept it.